# $\frac{1}{a} = \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} - \frac{1}{abc}$ and $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$

Tags: contest-math, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

I have found this in an Romanian magazine. We have to solve for natural numbers:
$$\frac{1}{a} = \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} - \frac{1}{abc}$$
$$a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 = c ^ 2$$

After some elementary calculations, we get that $bc + 1 = a(b + c)$. I tried using some divisibility things, hoping to get $b + c$ dividing some constant, but, in the end, got $b + c \ | \ (b + c) ^ 2$. Then, $a^2(b + c) ^ 2 = (bc + 1) ^ 2$, so $(c^2 - b^2)(b + c)^2  =(bc + 1) ^ 2$  and tried solving this, but, again, couldn't. Can you help me? I doubt there are natural solutions, but are there any integers?

Comment: The derived equation is satisfied with  a=1, b=0, and c=1.  Unfortunately the original equation has $\infty$.

Comment: $(a,b,c)=(8, 15, 17)$ works...

Comment: Sorry guys I did an oopsie @Dr.Mathva

Answer (score 2):

(This is not a solution. I made an error.)

Show that  (If you get stuck, show your work.)

1. $(a, b, c)$ is a primitive pythagorean triplet.
2. If $(a, b, c ) = (m^2 - n^2, 2mn, m^2+n^2)$ with $m > n > 0$, then there are no solutions.

> Substituting in, we get $n^4 = m^4 - 4mn^3$.
>  View this as a quartic in $ x = \frac{n}{m}$, we get $ x^4 + 4x^3$ - 1 = 0, which has no rational solutions.
>  Hence, there are no integer solutions to $(m, n)$.

3. If $(a, b, c) = ( 2mn, m^2 - n^2, m^2 + n^2)$ with  $m > n > 0$, then the only solution is $(m, n) = (4, 1) $ which leads to $ (a, b, c) = (8, 15, 17)$.

(Hm, I thought I had a solution to this part, but it turns out that I made an error.)

> Substituting in, we have $ m^4 - 4m^3 n= n^4 - 1$.
>  If $ n = 1$, we have $ m = 4n = 4$.
>  Otherwise, writing it as $ m^3 (m-4n) = n^4 - 1 > 0 \Rightarrow m -1 \geq 4n$.

Comment: Sorry, but why is $(a, b, c)$ a primitive pythagorean triple?

Comment: And can all pythagorean triplets be written as  $(m^2 - n^2,  2mn, m^2 + n^2)$? I have not really worked with the Pythagorean  Theorem outside geometry.

Comment: @andueu A) As I stated, "Show that (If you get stuck, show your work)". So, show your work. B) Yes, that's a well-known fact. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple)

Comment: I think I have managed to show that $(a, b, c)$ is a primitive pythagorean triple. If we supposed that $(a, b, c)$ is a solution of the system, with $a, b, c$ coprime, then, I assumed that $(ka, kb, kc)$ is also a solution. Substituting this in the first equation, we get $\frac{1}{a} = \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} - \frac{1}{abck^2}$, which is absurd since $\frac{1}{a} = \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} - \frac{1}{abc}$. Is it correct?

Comment: @andueu No. Your reasoning doesn't make sense. If $(a, b, c)$ is a solution of the system, why would $(ka, kb, kc)$ be a solution of the system (and vice versa)?

Comment: @Calvin, $(m,n)=(4,1)$ is only natural solution of $m^4 - 4m^3 n= n^4 - 1$?

Comment: @Tomita I believe yes (as does Wolfram), but do not have a proof of that as yet. That's the only gap I have so far (potentially a large gap).

Comment: @Tomita It doesn't need to have 4 (not necessarily distinct) integer solutions. EG It could have 1 integer, 1 irrational, 2 complex solutions.

Comment: @Tomita I don't understand that you mean. If you think you have a solution, please write it up in full.